# Indexing column name in R

Tags: r, indexing

I have a data frame like as follows,

```
    > df
  A B C D E
1 1 2 3 4 5
2 4 5 6 7 7
3 7 8 9 8 9
```

where rows are Genes and Column are Sample Ids, I want to index the normal/disease samples. Normal samples are A, B and disease samples are D & E (For example). I have a Phenotypic file as follows

```
> Pheno
      sample status
    1 A         Normal
    2 B         Normal
    3 C         Unknown
    4 D         Diseased
    5 E         Diseased
```

Now my question is How to index samples in 'df', say, for example, == 0 for normal and == 1 for Diseased in R based on Pheno file classification. (Indexing samples into Normal and Diseased from RNAseq raw counts file. with 758 samples as columns and 556789 genes as rows) Hope I am clear, it would be great if you can help me in this.Thanks a lot for your help

Regards,

Have a great day,

Dave.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output given your example input ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I wanted to apply voom function from limma package to normalize the data. so I want to group the data into two conditions like Normal and disease in a file (df) . for creating a design matrix. (Like test and training groups)

Comment: @David, you can edit your post and write your expected output. Would you like, for example, to replace the contents of `df` by 0 or 1 depending on whether they are normal or diseased?

Comment: The expected out put is to group the data into two sets and normalising it using a package called limma. here i am not supposed to change any content of df.